# How to Inherit a Page into a Class in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a class in asp.net and I want to inherit the Main Page. I have tried below but it has an error:

```
Public Class Class1
Inherits Main Page

End Class
```

In windows Application inheriting form is much easier than in asp.net. Just like below:

```
Public Class Class1
Inherits FormMain

End Class
```

Can someone help me on inheriting page in a class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Main Page** is not a valid name for a class. What is your base page's class name?

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to inherit from your Main page's class.

Comment: Are you trying to inherit the page, or are you trying to create a class for reuse across your entire application? You can inherit from System.Web.UI.Page to create a class you can use as the basis for all your pages that have common functionality. You can also create a Master.Page if what you are trying to do is create a common UI throughout your application. You can actually also do both together.

Comment: I am trying to inherit a page into a class. Is that possible?

Comment: @Dai..I am trying to inherit the page into a class to access all controls on that page

Comment: Why do you want to have access to the controls? You could make the controls public, or you could create public attributes or methods to get values settings from the controls. Why do you need to inherit from that? If you give us a little more information of what you are trying to achieve it would help greatly.

Comment: Also, not sure what you experience with asp.net is like, but from your question, I am assuming you are coming from a WinForms background. You must remember that web development is a stateless environment, so what ever the state of the controls in the page, you need to deal with them on the postback event. #JustPurelyGuessing where you heading.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name must be a single word. Try Main_Page or MainPage since in many cases the underscore character is hidden by other elements or the cursor.

Otherwise, search you project for the class and make sure you are using the same name as the actual implementation of the class.

Comment: The class name was Class1 not Main Page.

Comment: The class doing the inheriting is Class1. I was referring to the class you are trying to inherit FROM.

Comment: I am trying to inherit from a web form named MainPage

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not something you want to really do. The web page in ASP.NET WebForms consists of two parts - Design and Code-behind. The design part is translated into rendering Visual Basic code during compilation.

I can't see a reason for deriving from a WebForms page. What are you trying to achieve? You can certainly change the base class the page uses, but there is practically no logical reason to derive from it.

EDIT:
You might be actually trying to do something in the sense of having a base page and then other pages that have the same basic "structure". That is possible, but using a different ASP.NET mechanism called MasterPages (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX)

Comment: He doesn't want to inherit from WebForms, it was an example he was giving.

Comment: I think that MainPage is actually a ASP.NET WebForms page, but you are right that it is not specified.

Comment: @MZetko...yes sir it is the ASP.NET webforms page that I am trying to inherit into class to access all its controls

Comment: No need to use that formal language here ;-) . Why exactly do you want to do this? If you want to have a basic structure that you want to reuse on all pages, then the Master Pages I mentioned are a much better solution (and probably the only one that makes sense here).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your MainPage is your inheriting class, then make sure it's declared something like:

```
''' <summary>
''' Base page for all other web pages in the system.
''' </summary>
Public Class MainPage

    Inherits Page

...

End Class
```

Your ASP.NET class would then be:

```
Public Class Class1

Inherits MainPage

...

End Class
```